# How do I redirect a domain and specific URIs with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a MantisBT installation that I want to redirect to GitHub.  For specific issues, there exists a corresponding issue at GitHub, so I want to treat those 'view' URIs first. Then all other URIs should just go to 'issues'.

```
# send the bare domain to GitHub issues
rewrite ^/$ https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/ permanent;

# https://issues.slicer.org/view.php?id=4725 => https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/4725
location ~ ^/view.php {
  # rewrite ^.*$ https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/$arg_id permanent;
  return 301 https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/$arg_id;
}

# Send all remaining URIs to github issues    
rewrite ^ https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues permanent;
```

The problem I'm having is that the view.php rule is not working properly.  I'm getting 
`https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues?id=1234` instead of
`https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/1234`

Answer (score 0):

I simplified my configuration to the following, and it's working now as intended.

```
# View URIs like https://issues.slicer.org/view.php?id=4725
location ~ ^/view.php {
  # rewrite ^.*$ https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/$arg_id last;
  return 301 https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues/$arg_id;
}
# everything else
location ~ (?!view) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/issues? permanent;
}
```